# why unable to pass project_id to Task Model in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

need to  pass project model id as project_id to the Task model and save.
this is My TaskController  method

```
public function postNewTask(Request $request, Project $project)
{
    $task = new Task;
    $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
    $task->body = $request->input('body');
    $task->assign = $request->input('status');
    $task->priority = $request->input('status');
    $task->duedate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input("date")));
    $task->project_id = $project->id;

     // This will set the project_id on task and save it
    $project->tasks()->save($task);

}
```

this is Task Model

```
class Task extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = ['task_name', 'body', 'assign','priority','duedate','project_id'];

         public function scopeProject($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }
      public function projects()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
     }
```

this is form action of My task related data saving

```
<form  method="post" action="{{ route('projects.tasks.create', $project->id) }}">
```

and this is My routes

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/tasks', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@postNewTask',
    'as' => 'projects.tasks.create'
]);
```

but I got this error messages

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'project_id' cannot be null
```

how can i solved this problem. why unable to pass `project_id`

Comment: have you checked whether value of project id is there or not? Because error clearly says it is passing NULL to task object

Comment: I found some error in My Migration files that means I did not put primary and forign key as well between My project and Task files is this problem with this mattes